# Is it good practice to check the requirement multiple times?

Tags: tdd

When writing tests for TDD is it good (or bad) practice to write multiple test for the same requirement ? If it's good how many times should it be repeated? If it's bad is it it the QA engineers work to do so?

E.g. Testing a calculator that adds 2 numbers.

```
# import stuff here   
def test_Cal(self):
   self.assertEqual(Calculator.cal(self,1,2),3)
```

Is this enough or should I write

```
# import stuff here   
def test_Cal(self):
   self.assertEqual(Calculator.cal(self,1,2),3)
   self.assertEqual(Calculator.cal(self,10,12),22)
   self.assertEqual(Calculator.cal(self,9,9),18)
```

Comment: It is certainly not a good idea to jam multiple cases into one test like that - look into _parameterised_ testing, where you run a test for each separate case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Classic TDD suggests writing a *single* example, then writing the code that makes the example work. If there are more requirements that are not covered by this example, then adding new examples and writing more code makes sense. By itself, adding more examples doesn't demonstrate anything useful. But more examples can be interesting if those examples are chosen to exercise edge cases or boundary values, for example to test how your calculator deals with negative numbers, zeros, or very large numbers.

It is often recommended that each test case should only assert a single thing. This doesn't mean that every test method should literally only have a single assert, but that unit tests should fail for a clear cause. Thus, multiple examples that describe different requirements should likely be given in separate methods. In practice, this is often not seen as strictly, and a single test case might contain checks for multiple aspects of the same requirement.

In TDD, the act of writing tests is about discovering and documenting requirements. It is thus always done by the developer writing the code, and cannot be outsourced to a different person. Of course, “real” TDD is not common. Your specific organization might indeed delegate some responsibilities to a dedicated QA role, but that would have nothing to do with TDD itself.

While TDD generally implies an example-based test strategy, it is not always necessary to manually specify those examples. In property-based testing, the tests describe relationships between inputs and outputs, and the test framework is responsible for generating lots of examples – a kind of fuzz testing. For example, Python has the `hypothesis` framework for this:

```py
from hypothesis.strategies import integers
from hypothesis import given

@given(integers(), integers())
def test_Cal(self, a, b):
  self.assertEquals(Calculator.cal(a, b), a + b)
```

This tests that for any integers A and B, the calculator will produce the sum, without having to select a specific example manually.

Answer (score 3):

In TDD, you usually start with *one* test:

```
def test_Cal(self):
   self.assertEqual(Calculator.cal(self,1,2),3)
```

(Let's assume your goal is to make `cal` just to add its inputs).

Next, you start implementing the function so it makes the test succeed. In case you implement it as `return x+y`, this test is probably sufficient. In case you start with a simpler implementation like `return 3`, you may have to add a second test, until you come to the conclusion that `return x+y` is what makes most sense.

Then you look at *your implementation* of `Calculator.cal`, check code and branch coverage achieved by the tests, think about edge cases which might be problematic and reflect about how much you trust the tests whether they are sufficient for validating the known requirements, or not. And if not, you add more tests - not by blindly picking some arbitrary numbers, but by thinking what kind of test input may cause a different execution path, or some unexpected result.

For example: as long as `Calculator.cal` is simply a wrapper around `+`, the first test is probably sufficient. But in case `Calculator.cal` has different behaviour for negative numbers, or for numbers of a certain size, or has different behaviour depending on the internal state of the calculator object, then you should add more tests for exactly those cases, one by one, right before you implement the related functionality.

It is also a good idea to check if the number of tests is sufficient before refactoring the implementation to make sure not breaking anything by the refactoring.

This is why I prefer to think about TDD as a **"white-box"** testing technique: even if you design tests before any code is written, you make decisions about adding more tests by using your knowledge about the existing implementation.

Answer (score 3):

To some extent, this is a question that [Mutation Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation_testing) seeks to answer: are the tests sufficient to identify all possible bugs, but with no redundant testing?

Without seeing the code under test, it's hard to say whether you have insufficient, excess, or just the right amount of testing.  Any test that can't be made to fail independently of other tests is a candidate for removal; any bug you can introduce that's not detected indicates that more tests are needed.

Without the rigour of mutation testing, we usually find that after satisfying our first test, there's either a requirement we can see isn't satisfied or part of our code that's implemented but not exercised.  That determines what test to add next.  Only when we've run out of untested implementation code and unsatisfied requirements are we complete.

Normally, I'd expect to end up with tests of some trivial cases (0 + 0, for example) a few happy-path cases (perhaps two distinct positive numbers, two distinct negative ones, and one with different signs, if that exercises different code paths) and a selection of edge cases (e.g. maximal values, infinities, NaNs).